# better from ListView & Scroll View?

Tags: android

I have to show some LinearLayouts in Scroll. I am using ListView but got some problems in that.
I want to change the listView to scrollView. IS there any special benefit of using ListView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListView will draw and load only the visible views. If you have a lot of data to display, the ScrollView will create all the "row" views which could lead to out of memory error or slow UI.

Comment: Ok..But what problem i am facing is when i scroll the list four or five times it get a crash saying null pointerException in Adapter. what may be the problem?

Comment: some object you are using to build the views must be null. Use your debugger and the stack trace to find the problem. (or paste code + stack traace in the question)